# Trying to make off-screen UICollectionViewCells pre-render using a custom layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a paged UICollectionView, with one cell per page. However, my UICollectionViewCells are slow to render (third party library, no options there). So as an optimisation, i need to pre-render the cells to the left and right of the current page, so scrolling is smooth.

What i've done is, inside my custom UICollectionViewLayout, is outset the passed rect by 1 point before checking to see which cells' UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes should be returned, see here:

```
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGRect outsetRect = CGRectInset(rect, -1, 0);
    return [_myAttributes filter:^BOOL(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attribs) {
        return CGRectIntersectsRect(attribs.frame, outsetRect);
    }];
}
```

This works as expected. However, when the actual UICollectionView does its thing, it seemingly ignores the offscreen cells and calls `cellForItemAtIndexPath` only for the first cell, not the cell to the right (or left).

Any ideas what is going on? Thanks

Comment: Options i'm considering are: Cells that are offscreen, return their coords as though they are onscreen, with a z-index that puts them behind the main 'visible' cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, i solved this by:

- Making cells for pre-rendering forcibly moved on-screen a little, but with the same size.
- Changing their z-index to -1 so they are under the main page cell.
- In the layoutAttributesForElementsInRect, check if the rect is two pages wide, and if so then it's scrolling between pages, so don't grab any extra pages
- In my cell's applyLayoutAttributes, i check if the z-index<0, and if so, then this is a pre-rendering cell.

Cheers